# SQL Sort By a Column and group by another column simultaneously

Tags: sql, sorting, group-by, sql-order-by

Raw Table : Jobs

```
| Amount |  Name |
        3    Raj
        1    Nish
        15   Nish
        10   Nish
        8    Krish
        22   Rahul
        5    Raj
        50   Raj
```

Required result format

```
 | Amount |  Name |
        50    Raj
         5    Raj
         3    Raj
        22    Rahul
        15    Nish
        10    Nish
         1    Nish
         8    Krish
```

The  logic i am applying is sort the amount column and get the max amount i.e (50) and get
the other transaction of that person (Raj) and continue to search the second max item excluding the already selected person detail(excluding Raj).

Please help me with this

I Tried order by first "Amt" and then by "name" but it will not yield result as expected

Comment: which dbms ? sql server or mysql ?

Comment: @Notulysses Tried it is not working

Comment: @mhasan sql server 2012

Comment: ORDER BY Name DESC,AMOUNT DESC

Comment: @Mihai I tested your solution and it works. Can you explain why?

Comment: @Andre When you have text,it orders alphabetically the rest is common sense.

Comment: @Mihai this wont work if Krish had the max amount ..

Comment: @mhasan Why, could you go in depth a bit?Wont it order first by name so Krish will be last no matter the amount?

Comment: @Mihai yes you are correct but thats not what the author wanted. If the name of Krish is 'Andre' its possition on the result should be the same.

Comment: @Andre Tried your solution but it give priority for name sorting it will not look for amt sorting

Comment: @Andre the solution i m looking is find the max amount and get all the other details based on name and continue to search for second largest amount excluding the alreday selected items.

Comment: @Nishanth Could you add a second sample? Maybe with sloghtly different amounts? I am not sure I get your question correct.

Comment: I think your desired results are a bit off.Raj should have 3 not 1 in the third row.

Comment: @Mihai yes Sorry For mistake

Comment: @Mihai the solution you gave in that the second order by element will not behave as expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement will give each name with its maximum amount.

```
select name, max(amount) as max_amt
from jobs
group by name
order by max_amt desc;

Raj    50
Nish   25
Rahul  22
Krish   8
```

Sorting on `max_amt desc` gives us the groups in the right order. Now all we need to do is join that to the "jobs" table, and sort the result by the two numerical columns.

I used a CTE to simplify things a bit.

```
with max_amounts as (
  select name, max(amount) as max_amt
  from jobs
  group by name
)
select t1.*, t2.max_amt from jobs t1
inner join max_amounts t2 
        on t2.name = t1.name
order by max_amt desc, amount desc;
```

In standard SQL, I think you can just remove max_amt from the outer SELECT clause, and still use `order by max_amt desc`.

Comment: If you have more columns, then you will understand, this is not working!

Answer (score 3):

```
create table SORT_AMT_NAME(AMOUNT INT,NAME VARCHAR(20))


INSERT INTO SORT_AMT_NAME Values (22,'Rahul')
INSERT INTO SORT_AMT_NAME Values (8,'Krish')
INSERT INTO SORT_AMT_NAME Values (15,'Nish')
INSERT INTO SORT_AMT_NAME Values (1,'Nish')
INSERT INTO SORT_AMT_NAME Values (10,'Nish')
INSERT INTO SORT_AMT_NAME Values (50,'Raj')
INSERT INTO SORT_AMT_NAME Values (3,'Raj')
INSERT INTO SORT_AMT_NAME Values (5,'Raj')
INSERT INTO SORT_AMT_NAME Values (25,'GS')




SELECT AMOUNT,SORT_AMT_NAME.NAME FROM SORT_AMT_NAME,
(
select MAX(AMOUNT) AS MAX_AMT,NAME,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by MAX(AMOUNT) desc) as Amount_Order
from SORT_AMT_NAME
GROUP BY NAME) x
WHERE X.NAME=SORT_AMT_NAME.nAME
ORDER BY Amount_Order ASC ,AMOUNT DESC,SORT_AMT_NAME.NAME
```